# How to merge in vim an edited file when the file has also been edited externally?

Tags: vim, merge

Suppose you have opened a file in vim, then you edit it (or a program edit it) externally, but you keep working on the previous version of the file (cause you forgot it has been modificated).

How do you merge the current version with the externally modificated ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yank the whole buffer: `:%y`.
2. Open a new buffer in a new vertical window: `:vnew`.
3. Paste: `Vp`.
4. Go back to the previous buffer: `<C-w>p`.
5. Force reload it: `:e!`.
6. Diff the two buffers: `:windo diffthis`.

In one go:

```
:%y|vnew|0put|wincmd p|e!|windo diffthis
```

See `:help diff`.